# How to create a Client Secret using Terraform?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create a Client_secret for My service principal using the below code :

```
data "azuread_service_principal" "existing_SP" {
  display_name = "TestAppRegistration"
}
resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "Client_Secret" {
  service_principal_id = data.azuread_service_principal.existing_SP.object_id
}
```

Doing a terraform-apply it get successfully created but I don't see it in the Secrets and certificates section of the app registration:

[image]

But when I check the tfstate , it shows the value there created for the service principal but the object Id is same as the enterprise application present for the same app registration:

[image]

So, My question:

1. How can I create a client secret using terraform, is there something I am doing wrong ?
2. If I am doing correct then where is the secret generated can be found in portal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I create a client secret using terraform, is there something I
> am doing wrong ?

Yes , You are doing everything correctly.

But to clear the confusion here , as you may already know there are 2 types of `azure ad application` i.e. `app registrations` and `enterprise application`. In terraform or powershell or cli the `App Registration` is know as `Azure AD application` and the `Enterprise Application` for the same app registration is know as `Service Principal`. So , if you have created from Portal by going to app registration blade , then bydefault a service principal is created for it , but its not the same if you create a app registration from Powershell or Terraform.

And By default `you will be not be able to see the secret or certificate created for service principal from portal` but you will be defintely able to use it with the client-id for authentication purpose .

**For example :**

I tested this on my environment using your code and I took the value of password present in tfstate file and used it to do az login:

[image]

**Note:** Its safe to use terraform for creating a service principal password as it will be stored in the tfstate file so, you won't face difficulty in searching for it .

> If I am doing correct then where is the secret generated can be found
> in portal?

But if you are trying to look for the secret from portal , then I will suggest you to use `azuread_application`:

```
data "azuread_application" "example" {
  display_name = "postman"
}
resource "azuread_application_password" "example" {
  display_name = "terraformgenerated"
  application_object_id = data.azuread_application.example.object_id
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate for the detailed explanation:)

Comment: Glad to be of Help @UserP!!

Comment: is there a possibility to assign a group to this app with TF?